# A learning gomoku in Lisp

Tags: unix, identify-this-game, lisp

Years ago I played a version of gomoku that was written in Lisp that learned as you played. After a few rounds, it became nearly unbeatable. This was on Unix System III on a small PDP-11.

I have searched quite a bit for that Lisp code and haven't been able to find it. The versions I've found haven't been the one I'm looking for. Also, I'm not looking for one that requires Emacs. Unfortunately, I don't remember any more details.

Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: Was it when you were in Uni or was it at work.?  If in Uni, it may have been someone's AI coursework/project.  We used to write such programs when I was in Uni - either write from scratch or continuing from the previous years' contributions.